# yadcf external trigger loads twice

Tags: javascript, datatables, yadcf

I am using jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js and //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.js with sAjaxSource

I'm trying to use external filters that triggers several columns to a pre-selected filter at once.  So you click a button and there, three columns are picked out so you don't have to go in each drop down.

But the way I'm doing it seems wrong, because I'm seeing two JSON requests instead of one every time they're triggered.

All I have in my script is

```
 function doTrigger(){
      yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[0,"zero"],[1,"one"]]);
      $("#yadcf-filter--oTable-" + 1).val("one");
      oTable.fnDraw();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this: I haveadded third argument `true`, its undocumented, but needed when calling the exFilterColumn after table finished loading

```
 function doTrigger(){
      yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable, [[0,"zero"],[1,"one"]], true);
 }
```

The rest of your code is not needed at all...

Comment: I'm not in my testing environment right now, but if I go to http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/ajax_source.html, type `yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable,[0,"KHTML"]);` it doesn't reload the page.  That's why I'm relying on `fnDraw()`

Comment: updated my answer, so in showcase the following will work `yadcf.exFilterColumn(oTable,[[0,"KHTML"]], true);`

Comment: @Daniel, this "true" really prevents the double ajax call, but if the externally_triggered option is used with it, it's ignored: the filter gets applied imediatelly when YADCF gets initialized. What I want to achieve is to avoid both datatables and YADCF to fire the initial ajax call, so I use externally_triggered, but I get the double ajax call, or the ajax is fired automatically.

Comment: @Marcovecchio please open a new issue on github and provide a test page with a minimal code needed so so it will be possible to fix it